# Distributions dual to functions of polynomial growth.

Tags: distribution-theory

The space of distributions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is essentially found by requiring that it should be possible to apply the distribution to any bump function. Similarly, compactly supported distributions can be applied to any smooth function.

Is there some space of distributions which can be applied to all functions of polynomial growth?
I'm fairly sure this condition should have been given a name by now but I'm struggling to find a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was unable to find any name for this type of distribution I have given it a name myself and proved that it works well. Here are the relevant notions:
[image]

Comment: The use of $\mathcal{S}$ is a bit unfortunate since that is already used for the [Schwartz spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space).

Comment: Thank you. Would there be conflicts if I used $\mathcal{P}$?

Comment: Not as far as I know. Not more than that some people might use $\mathcal P \frac1x$ for the principal value distribution. But that's at least another type of object.

Comment: I don't think these are useful definitions. The space unfortunately called $\mathcal{S}$ is most likely not complete. There is no need to reinvent the wheel. There are well studied spaces of smooth functions of temperate growth $\mathscr{O}_{\rm M}$ and $\mathscr{O}_{C}$. See the book by Schwartz (in French) or Horvath (in English).

Comment: The definition is usefull to me. I needed to be able to talk about some broad class of probability distributions for which (1) derivatives are well-defined (2) moments are well-defined.  

Nothing I could find on temperate distributions was precisely like this. Is your claim that my definition is already covered by some version of temperate distributions or that temperate distibutions are more useful to people in distribution theory (but not to me)?

Comment: A notion of space of smooth functions of temperate growth is a useful idea. The question is how to come up with a precise definition of TVS. As a set, your definition of $\mathcal{S}$ is exactly what in the distribution literature is called $\mathscr{O}_{\rm M}$. FYI, there is a strict subspace $\mathscr{O}_{C}$ where the degree of growth is uniform for all derivatives. The dual $\mathscr{O}'_{C}$ is called the space of distributions of rapid decay and may be what you may want at the end of the day. What is not useful is your definition of topology for $\mathscr{O}_{M}$. Read Horvath.